# Drupal7 Menu item 'title callback' being cached?

Tags: 7, routes

I defined a menu through hook_menu, and set a title callback on a menu item, like so:

```
function mymodule_foobar_menu() {
     $items[SOMEPATH] = array(
    'title'         => t('Drink'),
    'title callback' => 'mymodule_foobar_menu_title',
    'access callback' => (blah),
        'page callback' => 'blah',
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
        'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
        '#description' => '',
        'weight'=>10
    );
```

and created

```
function mymodule_foobar_menu_title() 
{
    return ($whatever)?t('Beer'):t('Wine');
}
```

mymodule_foobar_menu_title seems to be called for almost everywhere where 'Drink' would appear, showing 'Beer' or 'Wine' instead. Except, in the main menu itself.

I can edit the main menu (at admin/structure/menu/manage/main-menu) and I see the link mentioned as Wine (or Beer). If I edit the link, there is a textbox 'Menu link title *' that says 'Drink'.

Can someone explain how to change the text of the link, instead of all the other appearances of the title, preferably without using an extra module ?

Comment: I think the title callback is for the page, not the menu link (routes and links are two separate things even though `hook_menu()` convolutes them a bit). The simplest solution I can think of would be to install [Menu Token](https://drupal.org/project/menu_token) and define a custom token in your module

Comment: Aw, that makes sense. I would like a solution without Yet Another Module, though. Updating the question.